# InfoPath Contact Selectors in Repeating Section

Tags: infopath

I have a repeating section that contains 3 contact selectors which loads different data for a given object. When I click use the "`run query`" option to load all of my objects, they are correctly populated for the first item. However, instead of loading all the correct values for the remaining objects, the same values are used for every other object instead of loading them individually for the given object.

Each contact selector is in its own group so that when I choose a value, the others aren't affected. However, if I have more than one object visible (by object I mean group of fields in a repeating section) the value for the corresponding field in the contact selector for the other objects gets set to the same value.

How can I make it so that these objects are treated separately?