# InfoPath - Populating a combo box with AD users from a web service

Tags: infopath

I have the need to populate a combobox in InfoPath with all the users from our Active Directory system.  I'd also like this combo box to have auto-complete   Can someone please point me in the right direction to accomplish this?  Everything I find on the web seems to only load the currently logged-in user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sharepoint server on your domain you can take advantage of contact selector control described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/02/28/using-the-contact-selector-control.aspx).

Otherwise you will be to forced to create some code in C#. Basiclly you have two options

1. Create custom control in C# and use it in infopath. [Tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2005/04/15/creating-an-infopath-custom-control-using-c-and-net.aspx)
2. Create standard infopath combobox and bind it to dynamically created collection in custom C# code.

This will be needed for both options: [Extensive tutroial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx) how to use class from DirectoryServices namespace.

Based on the comment I think you should take a look at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2009/04/29/using-multiple-contact-selector-controls-in-a-single-infopath-form.aspx) about adding multiple contact selector controls into one infopath form and also [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointinfopath/thread/96ebd192-40f0-4e7c-bdd7-af9959ee2b28).

Comment: We do have a Sharepoint server and I initially tried using Contact Selectors.  However, I ran into a problem where when I load multiple items in a repeating section, the Contact Selector populates all the items with the values from the first item.   I will check out your links.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks baalazamon.  I ran into this problem a while ago but have since figured out that you need to assign them to different groups.  The problem I'm having is a little different.  It's only one contact selector on the form, but it's inside of a repeating section, so when I click the button to 'run query', all the contact selectors are loaded with the same values the first item has.

Comment: I think you should create additional post with different tile e.g. "Infopath contact selector inside repeating section". I don't have right now access to AD server and infopath so can't help more. But first try this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointinfopath/thread/96ebd192-40f0-4e7c-bdd7-af9959ee2b28

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888354/infopath-contact-selectors-in-repeating-section  I'll take another look at that thread, although if you'll look you'll see I tried responding to that thread as well!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's true I haven't looked at the name :) sorry. If you like the response you can mark it as answer. You should add to your answer this thread as you already tried that and some more details it will be easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a bit of learning to do here I am afraid. You'll need to write an LDAP query to get this information. LDAP is a bit of a chore to learn. Using .NET, you can get some help from System.DirectoryServices namespace for help. e.g.:

```
        var searcher = new DirectorySearcher("(objectCategory=user)");
        var results = searcher.FindAll();
        for (int i=0; i<results.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(results[i].GetDirectoryEntry().Name);
        }
```

You'll probably need to refine the filter to limit searches to a particular OU to avoid returning service accounts and the like. You'll also want to look at pulling back properties for the user's Fullname etc.

Another route that might be MUCH easier is if your domain has Exchange, you could use the Exchange web service to query the global address list?

Comment: Thanks.  We do have an exchange server on our domain.  How do I access the Exchange web service.  The web service URL I am using is: http://rginfonet/_vti_bin/userprofileservice.asmx?WSDL